# Issue with initializing database with EF

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I'm trying to initialize a database with sample data and I get an error:

> Failed to set database initializer of type
>   'Blog.Models.DAL.BlogInitializer,Blog' for DbContext type
>   'Blog.Models.DAL.BlogContext, Blog' specified in the application

Inner exception is like that:

> Can't find a file or an assembly 'Blog' or one of its dependencies.
>   Can't find the specified file.

I have Blog.Model and Blog.WebUI in separate projects in the same Blog solution.
I have edited Web.config (In Blog.WebUI) file like that:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="BlogContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Blog;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>

  <entityFramework>
    <contexts>
      <context type="Blog.Models.DAL.BlogContext, Blog">
        <databaseInitializer type="Blog.Models.DAL.BlogInitializer, Blog" />
      </context>
    </contexts>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

In Server Explorer I see an accessible database created by it, but no tables inside.

BlogContext class:

```
namespace Blog.Models.DAL
{
    public class BlogContext : DbContext
    {

        public BlogContext() : base("BlogContext")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    }
}
```

And initializer:

```
namespace Blog.Models.DAL
{
    public class BlogInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<BlogContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(BlogContext context)
        {
            var posts = new List<Post>
            {
                new Post { Title="sadasd", Content="asdsa", Date=DateTime.Parse("2016-11-13"), Language="pl" },
                new Post { Title="sadasd", Content="asdsa", Date=DateTime.Parse("2016-11-13"), Language="pl" },
                new Post { Title="sadasd", Content="asdsa", Date=DateTime.Parse("2016-11-13"), Language="pl" },
                new Post { Title="sadasd", Content="asdsa", Date=DateTime.Parse("2016-11-13"), Language="pl" },
                new Post { Title="sadasd", Content="asdsa", Date=DateTime.Parse("2016-11-13"), Language="pl" }
            };

            posts.ForEach(p => context.Posts.Add(p));
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Go to your project "Properties" and check the assembly name what it is?

Comment: What a good question, you just solved my issue, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF failed to instantiate the database initalizer for your `DbContext` instance named `BlogContext`.

In the configuration you have configured the correct value for type of your database initializer which is correct:

```
<contexts>
  <context type="Blog.Models.DAL.BlogContext, Blog">
    <databaseInitializer type="Blog.Models.DAL.BlogInitializer, Blog" />
  </context>
</contexts>
```

The issue is that you're not using the correct assembly name `Blog`. You need to go to your project **"Properties"** via the context menu or **Alt + F4** and copy the correct assembly name. Then put it like this:

```
<contexts>
  <context type="Blog.Models.DAL.BlogContext, [The correct assemblby name]">
    <databaseInitializer type="Blog.Models.DAL.BlogInitializer, [The correct assemblby name]" />
  </context>
</contexts>
```